# How to retrieve a sub string that includes all the characters starting from the first "."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5

I am working on an asp.net web application. and I have many server names being retrieved from our ERP system, which include the server name and the domain name as follows:

- ABC.test.local
- ABC.test.local.co
- ABC
- ABC.local

So I am trying to find a way to always retrieve the domain name from the above. the rule is as follow. to extract all the characters from the first "." to the end?

So for the above 4 strings I will get:

- .test.local
- .test.local.co
- empty string
- .local

Can anyone advice on this please?

Thanks

Comment: Show the code that you have tried

Comment: @un-lucky to be honest I usually use .substring with Index value,, but not sure who to mentione to get the index from the first "."?

Comment: are you familiar with the string.Split() function also you can use `.Contains` method.. or `StartsWith or EndWith` there are a lot of different approaches to doing this.. however why don't you show us what you have actually tried on your own.. `IndexOf` is a good place to start too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This make it realy simple

```
string domain = "ABC";
domain = domain.Contains(".") ? domain.Substring(domain.IndexOf(".")) : string.Empty;
```

Comment: It could be different than just ABC. He used it just for example. He actually wanted text from first dot.

Comment: I know, it will work with all text in his example. It show all text after first dot and when there is no dot it will be empty string

Answer (score 0):

You really should list the code you've tried and were your stuck. According to your comment you use index value. This is exactly the same thing and gets the results you want.

```
string tString = "ABC.test.local";
        int ind = tString.IndexOf('.');
        if (ind > -1)
            tString = tString.Substring(ind);
        else tString = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 string s = "ABC.test.local";
 int i  = s.IndexOf('.');
 s = s.Substring(i, s.Length - i);
```